# Is there any way to set minimum instances with basic scaling in Google Cloud Platform (App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, scaling

[Basic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine) has some substantial benefits over automatic scaling, e.g. longer limits on background task execution.

However, it appears from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#basic_scaling) that it is not possible to set a minimum number of idle instances in the basic scaling setup, which seems like a major oversight. The result is that during low usage, our application often winds down to a single B2 instance, and then as soon as even a couple of requests hit, starts throwing 500 errors, and fails to spin up new instances in time.

In the automatic scaling setup, we'd just increase the number of idle instances to solve this.

Our setup is:

```
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
   max_instances: 35
   idle_timeout: 10m
```

Of course we could hack this by adding a cron job to warmup instances frequently enough to require > 1 instance at all times, but this seems like a poor workaround.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is this a true current limitation of basic scaling?

Answer (score 2):

I have been frustrated about that for a long time now, but there is no way to have a minimum number of instances active for basic scaling

As you thought, a crontab would save the situation, but I wanted to implement it in a clean way, so I used https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron

In the specific, I implemented a dummy endpoint that will be called every 4 minutes. I chose 4 because the `idle_timeout` by default is 5 minutes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/admin/keepalive</url>
    <target>my-module</target>
    <description>Keepalive to get an always on instance with basic scaling</description>
    <schedule>every 4 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```